# Using a .bat file for integration to client

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to put together a .bat file program that presents readable information.  Basically, we have a application called vSphere that reads custom scripts directly from a xml file.  So there are xml elements that are passed into the the client.  Now, I have a similar situation where we are doing the same thing with vCloud.  The difference is that vCloud only reads data from a .bat file instead of a xml file..  If I wanted to do such a thing what would that look like..  Below is my psuedo code as I'm not completely familiar with .bat file syntax.  Is this how I can present the information to be read by the vCloud client?  The client already knows how to read the .bat file, I just need help with a control structure example of a .bat file to tackle this problem.

xml version:

```
<_type>viss.CustomizationExample</_type>
<changeExample>1341932956</changeExample>
```

.bat file version:

```
@echo off
SET ChangeExample=1341932956
if changeExample==""(
echo changeExample==ChangeExample
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code may work for you

```
@echo off   
set changeExample=1341932956  
echo %changeExample%
```

This will display the value of `changeExample 1341932956` on the cmd screen if you run the batch file is this what you wanted...

Answer (score 1):

Your almost there, just a couple of things.

To access a variable after setting it, without any special circumstances, you need to put `%`'s at each side of it to tell cmd that you want the value contained in it.

By default `if` is case sensitive, so you must first make sure that your variables are spelt 
correctly, also you need a space between the end of the `if` condition and the bracket.

Provided that this is the correct format for the batch (I don't have a clue what it actually wants to read) then this is the correct syntax

```
@echo off
SET ChangeExample=1341932956
if %ChangeExample%=="" (
echo changeExample==%ChangeExample%
)
```

I presumed you wanted to `echo` the variable contents rather than the string `ChangeExample`, if you just want the string remove the `%`'s.